# WSL - Dockerfile copy hides .npmrc coming from windows filesystem

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile, windows-subsystem-for-linux, .npmrc

Note: The project is in the Windows filesystem and not in the WSL (I do not have this trouble when I perform the same steps with the project inside the WSL filesystem, please don't suggest to just change this, I just need to understand the reasons it fails as it is).

We're having trouble running the npm install in our Dockerfile. The project has a ".npmrc", but when I run the docker compose up, the build fails with a 401 HTTP code. Checking the image contents, the .npmrc is not shown when running `ls`, but it is shown with the option `-a`: `ls -a`.

Seems to me that there is some issue when copying a `.filename` from a Windows filesystem using a WSL running but we do not know the reason and if this is really the case.

Any hint?

Project structure:

[image]